# Why is it impossible to register an activity with EventBus?

Tags: android, events

I'm working on an Android project which use `EventBus` to provide message to a client. I used the line of code below to initialize my bus and to register the activity.

```
bus = new EventBus();
bus.register(this);
```

I also created a method called onEvent but I've got the following error:

```
Subscriber "my_activity" has no methods called onEvent.
```

A lot of threads advice to use :

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
```

And create a method call `onEventMainThread` by not really helpful. The question is why after creating the method `onEvent`, the IDE tells that the method is never used.

Do anybody recognise this error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks @startoftext for your answer. 
I tried it but not really helpful. I finally switch to OTTO which has the same approach than EventBus (register an object, post on the bus ...).

```
Bus bus = new Bus();
bus.register(context);
bus.post(new MyObject(xxx));
```

So the difference between EventBus is on event method. @Subscribe is added (as describe below).

```
@Subscribe 
public void onAnswerEvent (MyObject mObject) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: No problem. Still it would be good to know what was wrong with EvenBus for you. Either way. Glad you found something that works.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using:

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
```

I am not sure why that didn't work because you did not post your onEvent method signature. but it could be the name you used. Should be like this:

```
public onEvent(EventObject event){...}
```

Your onEvent method should have the name "onEvent" with a single parameter. Basically the way that the GreenRobot EvenBus works is to look for methods named onEvent that take the argument type of the event being sent.

So for example if you want to send an object type FooEvent then do this.

1. Define a simple public pojo class called FooEvent
2. Create a method on your receiving class like:

   ```
   public void onEvent(FooEvent event){
      // handle event
   }
   ```
3. Register that receiving class like;

   ```
   EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
   ```
4. Send your event like this:

   ```
   EventBus.getDefault().post(new FooEvent());
   ```

   Hope that helps. If not please post your onEvent method signature. I will help if I can. Good luck.

Comment: Your explanation is very clear.. I followed exactly like that but I receive this warning  " method 'onEvent' never used". What could I be doing wrong? thanks

Comment: @A.Adam If I understand you correctly that warning can be safely ignored. It is because EventBus uses reflection to call the method at runtime. Android studio generally cant see that. If it bothers you use @SuppressWarnings("unused") to suppress it.